# Count the number of unique data in a table

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

I have a table in a database that stores the name of each User who accessed my application in PHP. I would like to make a function that calculates the number of unique users who accessed it so far (assuming a User can access it more than once). However, I have no idea how to make this count .

Comment: What do you mean by "unique" users?  Do you mean the number of *distinct* users?  Or do you mean the number of users who accessed the application exactly *once*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To count number of unique user you can

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `column_name`) FROM `table_name`
```